# How to vectorize a loop with many conditions?

Tags: c++, vectorization, sse, simd

I have the loop below. The goal is to perform an operation between all elements of an array `tmp` and store it in a scalar `b`. The operation is equivalent to an addition, so there is no specific execution order. For example if we have a + b + c + d, we can compute this in any order, which means (a+b) + (c+d) is possible as well. The same is applicable to this operation. However, there are some special conditions which lead to the result by different ways.

`tmp.e` and `b.e` are `longs`, while `tmp.x`and `b.x` are `doubles`.

Is there any form to compare all `tmp.e`, in for example pairs of 2 for SSE, and perform the correct computation of `b.x` accordingly. In all cases, it can be viewed as an addMul, in the first case it's just multiplying by 1, in others by 0 or BOUND. Is it possible to vectorize this? If so, how?

Thanks.

```
void op(vec& tmp, scalar& b)
{
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (b.e == tmp.e[i])
        {
            b.x += tmp.x[i];
            b.normalize();
            continue;
        }
        else if (b.e > tmp.e[i])
        {
            if (b.e > tmp.e[i]+1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            b.x += tmp.x[i] * BOUND;
            b.normalize();
        }
        else
        {
            if (tmp.e[i] > b.e+1)
            {
                b.x = tmp.x[i]; 
                b.e = tmp.e[i];
                b.normalize();
                continue;
            }
            b.x = b.x * BOUND + tmp.x[i];
            b.e = tmp.e[i];
            b.normalize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `b.normalize()` do, and do you have a SIMD implementation?

Comment: In your loop you're doing two things: you search for a special range of `tmp.e` and you sum `tmp.x[i]` over this range. Try to first search the range before summing. With struct-of-arrays you can do a compact search on `tmp.e[i]` only, then vectorise on `tmp.x[i]` using masking as Peter describes below.

Comment: It seems that you cannot know what branch of the if cascade to take at iteration i before having performed iteration i-1. So, no.

Comment: Right now it is not clear: 1) you say about some operation being commutative and associative, but it is not clear how it is related to the code you have posted; 2) what is `normalize`?
It would be great if you write what you want to get as result, instead of having other people guess what your code actually does.

Answer (score 3):

Per-element conditionals in SIMD code are usually handled by using a packed-compare instruction to generate a mask of all-zero and all-one elements.  You can use this to AND or OR vectors.  So e.g. you can increment only the elements that pass a test by using AND to produce a vector with 1 in elements that should be incremented, and 0 in elements that shouldn't, because 0 is the identity value for addition.  (x+0 = x).

You can also compute two results and then blend them together, according to a mask.  (using AND and OR, or using vector blend instructions.)

This method of doing SIMD conditionals is like a `cmov`: you have to compute both sides of the branch, even if all the elements you're processing in a vector take the same side of the branch.

---

It looks like your data is in struct-of-arrays format already.  So you could generate masks from operations on vectors of `e` values, for use with vectors of `x` values.  If `long` is 32bits, you could do a compare of 4 elements, and unpack-low and unpack-high to get two masks with 64bit elements to match your doubles.  If the arrays are small (so they'd fit in cache even `.e[]` taking as much space as `.x[]`), having the longs the same as the doubles means less unpacking.

---

Anyway, it doesn't look promising.  Too many conditions, and I have no idea what the whole thing is really trying to accomplish, and what restrictions there might be on the input data.  If I knew more about the problem, maybe I could think of a vectorized way to do some of it.

---

Oh, I think **another fatal flaw is that each iteration depends on the previous iteration, because it might modify `b`**.  So you can't vectorize to do multiple iterations in parallel, unless you can work out a rule for updating `b` based on the last vector element.

Comment: This code indeed seems to be subject to data dependencies across successive elements. In addition, there are five different cases to be distinguished in the loop body. Unless the pattern of cases taken across the iterations has special characteristics (such as long repetitions of the same case), this vectorization is hopeless.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a struct of arrays instead of an array of structures and the dependencies can be avoided by doing what I explained on my post. But because of all those conditions it seems kind of impossible to vectorize this.

Comment: @fc67: Oops, I guess I didn't scroll back to double-check the code while writing that.  I think I was assuming from the written text (without checking the code) that the array had the same struct format as your scalar, since the code omitted any type declarations.  Or maybe I was just getting pessimistic and assuming this part of the problem was worst-case just like everything else. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes, Any of you wisdom on something similar in [Image Convolution](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/ImageConvolution)? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi: I didn't look at the code, but I notice in the README that you found MSVC with `/fp:fast` is faster than gcc.  But you left out `-ffast-math` from gcc, so you should try adding that.  Also use `-march=native` to let it use AVX and anything else the build machine machine supports.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I even tried with `-Ofast` in GCC and still much slower. Any how I opened [Vectorized and Multi Threaded Image Convolution - How to Increase Performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172157). As a Vectorization wizard, I'd be happy for your input. Thank You.